# How much theoretical development is usually expected from a PhD student?

Tags: phd, research-process, advisor

My question is geared towards areas where there can be mathematical proofs.

Most papers I have seen consists of some theoretical insight/proof, then some experiments validating it. One example is this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05992.pdf) that shows a machine learning result.

My question: how much is expected from a PhD student in terms of theoretical analysis? or I'd like to hear other people's experience. In my experience, so far I have being left one mostly, which is of concern because I don't think I have the understanding or tooling to generate paper-worth proofs.

Comment: Have you asked this question to your advisor? Some PhDs consist pretty much entirely of theoretical proofs, for others the opposite is true (even in areas where there could be mathematical proofs, some papers can be purely experimental). What will be your focus?

Comment: I have. I think he might provide little insights, but I don't think he'll sit to deeply think about it. My focus is machine learning. I should have said in the question that I was rather interested in learning other people's experience; especially those who produce papers that had proofs.

Comment: I produced basically only papers with proofs, obviously I was expected to write and come up with many of them (with advice from advisor of course, especially in the beginning). I also know PhD students in my field who did entirely experimental PhDs, if any of their papers had proofs, they were not theirs. I am not in machine learning though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on many factors. Practically, it would depend on the lab you are working in. If you have supervisors who are Math heavy and do theoretical research, then you would be expected to work in that direction. Your Ph.D. proposal will explicitly talk about it.

However, if your lab is working on a lot of data, say with industry, and doing incremental research improvement with new algorithms then it might be a different scenario. This is partly because your work would be evaluated by data from the customers. Say you came up with a better search algorithm, you will have enough data to test your algorithms. However, you would be expected to have a sense of why your algorithm worked, and you should be able to explain it with a logical flow of thoughts and it should suffice.

Ideally, you should do a mix of both. Theoretical proofs are invaluable because they make your algorithm more trustworthy. Your search algorithm might tank with unseen data with different characteristics. However, hypothetically, if you had had a theoretical analysis done, proving that it will show accuracy in a specific range for a specific variation in data, that goes a long way in helping people to adopt your algorithm. And you will have an idea where your algorithm would go wrong.

At the end of the day, Ph.D. is done to improve the knowledge of mankind through research. Proofs are useful but not necessary. Proofs are useful but might not be sufficient. Proofs are not always feasible. Scientists would love to give proof so that engineers could feel confident.

You are doing a Ph.D., be brave to explore and learn. It will help in the long run. Start by reading proofs and trying to find flaws. It is fun. You might end up giving good mathematical proofs yourself. But if you do not, then still you can end up doing a great job with your research. Many such Ph.D. theses exist.